# How to free all the memory allocation without knowing the pointers or nodes in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, runtime, malloc

the `malloc();` in my program is returning a NULL after some runtime , I don't know why is that happen , I have tried `exit();`.
I am looking for some way to clear all the memory , for example filling it with known function then delete it .
or by return the memory to a specific position in the code.
`free();` function is not helpful with me cause all the memory allocation I am making I free it.

```
volatile char *dsd;
char *strduppp (const char *s) {
dsd =  malloc (strlen (s) + 1); //  stddr;// Allocate memory
if (dsd != NULL){ strcpy (dsd,s); USART_Transmit('m');}        // Copy string if okay
return dsd;                            // Return new memory
}

volatile char* arg[20];
volatile char** args ;
void split (char * message)
{
char* p;
p = strtok (message,",");

args =arg;  // (char**)malloc(8*sizeof(char*));
for (int  m = 0; p != NULL; ++m)
{
    if(m==6) { p = strtok(p, "@");}
    args[m] = strdup(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
//free(p);
//free(message);
}
```

for every `malloc();` I use `free();`

Comment: Post the code that gives you problems.

Comment: There are two main possibilities.  If you are running out of memory, you are not freeing every allocation — you have a memory leak.  Alternatively, you are messing up the memory by writing out of bounds and making `malloc()` think it is out of memory.  On the whole, I think the former is more likely. Are you on a constrained device — and embedded system?  If so, say so.  People are used to workstations with gigabytes of memory.  If you've got less, it is important to say so.

Comment: I detect extreme enthusiasm for `volatile`; are you sure that's all really necessary?  Volatile arrays of pointers bodes ill for your memory management.  Since you have a commented out `free(p)`, I'm worried; it is a pointer into the message passed into the function.  It should not be being freed ever.  The values stored in `args` need to be freed, as does `args`; they were allocated by `malloc()` inside `strdup()`.

Comment: for every call to strdup() a call to free() using the returned value from strdup()

Comment: Without the actual contents of a message, it is unknown if the split() function will work as expected.

Comment: the inner call to strtok() may or may not return a null value.  there needs to be a check of the returned value for != NULL before assigning it to the args[m] array

Comment: I am using free() for every malloc I used
What will make it writing out of bounds??!
yes I am using a micro controller 
I have been recommended to use Volatile to force the compiler to perform the code and not to optimize some parts of it
free(p) was a try and I am not using it now

Comment: for every call to strdup() a call to free() using the returned value from strdup()
I don't understand .

Comment: isn't there any way to force the memory to be empty ?